# Primefaces wizard in internet explorer is rendering the next button multiple times

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3, wizard

I have a page with a primefaces wizard that on Chrome is displaying correctly, instead in InternetExplorer (tested with IE9) as soon as the form gets updated it renders the next buttons or sometimes the whole wizard different times (i.e. on the page I see 2 or 3 next buttons).

I have the necessity to use more than one wizard on one page and one of those wizards needs to be usable in other instances and scenarios.

My solution was to create a component for the reusable wizard and use it in all the different instances.

Basically in short I have something like this in my code:

```
<p:wizard .. >
</p:wizard>
...
<myComponent:myWizard .. attr="" />
```

definition of **myComponent:myWizard**

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="bean" default="#{myWizardBean}" />
    <composite:attribute name="attr..." />
    <composite:attribute name="attr..." />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="myWizardContainer">        
        <p:panel styleClass="clearfix" header="Header #{cc.attrs...}">

            <p:panel id="myPanelId1">   
                <p:wizard id="myWizardId" showStepStatus="false"
                    nextLabel="#{resources['text.next...']}" backLabel="#{resources['text.back...']}" 
                    step="#{cc.attrs...}" showNavBar="true">        
                    <p:tab id="firstTab" title="#{resources['text.title...']}" >                            
                        <ui:include src="page1.xhtml"/>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab id="secondTab" title="#{resources['text.tab2.title']}">
                        <ui:include src="page2.xhtml"/>
                    </p:tab>                        
                </p:wizard>
            </p:panel>

        </p:panel>
        <p:commandButton id="save" process="@this" 
            value="Save" icon="ui-icon-disk"
            action="#{...}"
            update="@form"
            rendered="#{...}"
            />
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: check compatibility mode. It should *not* be on

Comment: It actually works well on IE10 but on IE9 even without the compatibility mode on doesn't work as expected. Is there another workaround for this?